# Using cURL and PHP for CACTI in Windows

Tags: php, curl, cacti

Recently tasked to monitor external webpage response/loading time via CACTI.  I found some PHP scripts that were working (pageload-agent.php and class.pageload.php) using cURL.  All was working fine until they requested it to be transferred from LINUX to Windows 2012R2 server.  I'm having a very hard time modifying the scripts to work for windows. Already installed PHP and cURL and both working as tested. Here are the scripts taken from askaboutphp.

class.pageload.php

```
<?php
class PageLoad {
var $siteURL = "";
var $pageInfo = "";
/*
* sets the URLs to check for loadtime into an array $siteURLs
*/
function setURL($url) {
    if (!empty($url)) {
        $this->siteURL = $url;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*
* extract the header information of the url 
*/
function doPageLoad() {
    $u = $this->siteURL;
    if(function_exists('curl_init') && !empty($u)) {
        $ch = curl_init($u);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        $pageBody = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->pageInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*
* compile the page load statistics only
*/
function getPageLoadStats() {
    $info = $this->pageInfo;

    //stats from info
    $s['dest_url'] = $info['url'];
    $s['content_type'] = $info['content_type'];
    $s['http_code'] = $info['http_code'];
    $s['total_time'] = $info['total_time'];
    $s['size_download'] = $info['size_download'];
    $s['speed_download'] = $info['speed_download'];
    $s['redirect_count'] = $info['redirect_count'];
    $s['namelookup_time'] = $info['namelookup_time'];
    $s['connect_time'] = $info['connect_time'];
    $s['pretransfer_time'] = $info['pretransfer_time'];
    $s['starttransfer_time'] = $info['starttransfer_time'];
    return $s;
}   
}
?>
```

pageload-agent.php

```
#! /usr/bin/php -q
<?php
//include the class
include_once 'class.pageload.php';
// read in an argument - must make sure there's an argument to use
if ($argc==2) {
//read in the arg.
$url_argv = $argv[1];
if (!eregi('^http://', $url_argv)) {
    $url_argv = "http://$url_argv";
}
// check that the arg is not empty
if ($url_argv!="") {

    //initiate the results array
    $results = array();

    //initiate the class
    $lt = new PageLoad();

    //set the page to check the loadtime
    $lt->setURL($url_argv);

    //load the page
    if ($lt->doPageLoad()) {
        //load the page stats into the results array
        $results = $lt->getPageLoadStats();
    } else {
        //do nothing
        print "";
    }

    //print out the results
    if (is_array($results)) {
        //expecting only one record as we only passed in 1 page.
        $output = $results;

        print "dns:".$output['namelookup_time'];
        print " con:".$output['connect_time'];
        print " pre:".$output['pretransfer_time'];
        print " str:".$output['starttransfer_time'];
        print " ttl:".$output['total_time'];
        print " sze:".$output['size_download'];
        print " spd:".$output['speed_download'];
    } else {
        //do nothing
        print "";
    }
}
} else {
//do nothing
print "";
}
?>
```

Thank you. any type of assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you be more specific on the problems encountered ?

Comment: Hi Gerard.  Basically I'm getting 0 info.  I can run cURL manually and get some info but running the scripts gives me 0 results.  Can you clarrfy if both scripts can run in Windows environment?

Comment: `eregi` is deprecated so that might be an issue depending on which version of php you have.

Comment: I installed PHP 5.6.14